# Is there any type trait way to get int type from range capacity desired?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, type-traits

Writing some container classes, I feel the urge to avoid using size_t for capacity and iteration just to cover every case. Say I want just a 50 sized thing, an unsigned char would do..But how can I template this type from a given desired capacity? Is there any type trait  for that?

```
template<class T, size_t capacity> MyBuffer{
 ...
 using IDX = intRequired<capacity>; // desired
 ...
 T & At(IDX at);
 IDX Lenght();

}
```

Comment: There is no trait like this in the C++ library. But it's not hard to implement one yourself, based on `numeric_limits`.

Comment: There is no existing type trait to do what you are asking for. But you can probably create one yourself, such as using `constexpr` statements to calculate the smallest byte size needed to hold the `capacity` value (1, 2, 4, or 8), then use some template specializations to pick a suitable data type based on that byte size (`uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`).

Comment: @walnut  I dont think I understand your point.  To access, store or test against the capacity(or size, or access with [] or At(), as in the snippet), the user require a type

Comment: @RemyLebeau Its way beyond my template abilities tho..

Comment: @walnut "Capacity" /= "size", not in general. This could conceivably be a buffer with a speciifed *maximum* capacity, but which may at any time contain fewer elements.

Answer (score 3):

No such type trait in the standard, but you can make something similar yourself:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>


template <auto capacity, typename... intTypes>
struct intRequiredImpl;

template <auto capacity, typename intType>
struct intRequiredImpl<capacity, intType> {
        using type = intType;

        // avoid overflow
        static_assert(capacity <= std::numeric_limits<type>::max(), 
                "Largest specified type is not capable of holding the capacity.");
};

template <auto capacity, typename SmallInt, typename... LargeInts>
struct intRequiredImpl <capacity, SmallInt, LargeInts...>  {
        using type = std::conditional_t <
                (capacity <= std::numeric_limits<SmallInt>::max()),
                SmallInt, typename intRequiredImpl<capacity, LargeInts...>::type>;
};

template <auto capacity>
using uintRequired = typename intRequiredImpl<capacity,
                                        std::uint8_t,
                                        std::uint16_t,
                                        std::uint32_t,
                                        std::uint64_t>::type;

int main() {
        uintRequired<50> i; // std::uint8_t
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got some help and ended up with this:

```
template<size_t Max>
    using BestFitUint = std::conditional_t < Max <= UINT8_MAX, uint8_t,
                            std::conditional_t < Max <= UINT16_MAX, uint16_t,
                                std::conditional_t< Max <= UINT32_MAX, uint32_t,
                                    std::uint64_t > > >;
```

Works fine, not sure how different from Ayxan answer.